# Can I overlay Google Logo on map or move it to top right?

Tags: google-maps, overlays

I am wondering if I could put an overlay element over Google logo on map, or change its place to top right. I have an example picture( link is below ) that I made overlaying Google logo. Please help to give some solutions with this issue! Thanks!

Example image: [Overlaying google map logo](http://img526.imageshack.us/i/googlemap.png/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience using Google maps there is nothing you can do to overlay the logo or the copyright string. And you shouldn't, it's there for a reason - you should give credit for the things you use that have been made by other people.

The only "solution" that I see is to place an overlay picture that is outside your map container and position it absolutely over the Google logo. But I hated this thought the instance it occured in my mind :)

I think you should change the design of your map overlays so that the logo will fit in.

Comment: Note: As per the Google Maps API terms of service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices. Map padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding

Comment: Google does allow the attribution to be moved provided it meets the following conditions. See here  https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide

Answer (score 6):

You could move the logo (or remove it) quite easily with CSS - it's positioned absolutely.  If you examine the map with Firebug, you can find the id of the logo div.

I wouldn't advise doing this, since it will break the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) (section 9.4)

Answer (score 3):

You do want the Google logo and attribution to be visible in your image.

However, **it is completely OKAY** to move the logo around, or even provide the attribution as a caption right under the image. See here:  https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide/

> **Do I need to use the text provided on the imagery?**
>
> The automatically generated Google logo and data provider attribution may only be removed or obstructed if reintroduced in a visible form elsewhere within the content (for example, in a photo caption below a Google Earth still). In other words, your text must be as visible as it would have been if you had used the default text that we provide.
>
> **What does the attribution text need to say?**
>
> If you’re not using the text provided directly on Google Maps and Google Earth imagery, the text of your attribution must say the name “Google” and the relevant data provider(s), such as “Map data: Google, DigitalGlobe”.
>
> You may customize the style and placement of the attribution text, as long as the text is legible to the average viewer or reader. Note that Google logos cannot be used in-line (for example, "These maps from [Google logo].")

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Google logo from standard maps API breaks the Terms of Service.

There is however a Google maps API for business, which gives you much more flexibility. The standard price is $10,000/year. If you enquire to them about it, a representative from Google will call you. You can ask the representative exactly what the legalities surrounding the logo for paying customers is.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Chris B. the logo can be move using CSS. Here is an example that uses javascript iso an external ccs file:

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = "#"+element.id+" div div a[target='_blank'] img[src*='google_white'] {top:-25px !important;} ";
document.head.appendChild(css);  
var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
```