# Relocate Google logo in MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have two buttons at each bottom corners of the `MapView`, partly obscuring the google logo in the bottom-left corner.

In order to comply with the terms and conditions of the API, I need to relocate the google logo to somewhere more visible. i.e. above the button.

The google API doc states that the google logo is drawn in the `onDraw()` method of `MapView` but I have no idea how to override it properly since google maps is closed source.

I could do this in iPhone by finding the correct `UIView` in the `MKMapView's` children but I can't figure out how I could do this in Android.

Comment: re: The bounty, needs to work on 2.2 at a minimum, but compatibility with newer versions is important, too.

Comment: Just FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968399/can-i-overlay-google-logo-on-map-or-move-it-to-top-right See AtomicCharles answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Google Maps SDK v2 for Android adds this functionality.

Use `GoogleMap.setPadding()` to add padding to the "active" area (including the Google logo and copyright notices) while still filling the full container.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding

Comment: this worked a treat! i needed a panel to slide up when a marker was clicked, and calling setPadding on the map and passing in the calculated height of the panel, moves the controls and logo above the panel. the map also automatically centres on the clicked marker which was nice.

Comment: Some one knows if it's possible in V1 API?

Comment: @lujop no the same thing is not possible in v1

Comment: Is a good answer, but the padding of the center of the camera gets affected too

Answer (score 29):

You can move the google logo with the help of the Tag assigned to it `GoogleWatermark`. In the below code i have moved it to top right corner of the screen.

```
View googleLogo = binding.missionMap.findViewWithTag("GoogleWatermark");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)googleLogo.getLayoutParams();
glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);
glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
googleLogo.setLayoutParams(glLayoutParams);
```

where `missionMap` is the framelayout to which the `MapFragment` has been added.

Comment: Great to know that it's tagged as "GoogleWatermark", thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and we need to add this code in onMapReady()

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, but you can achieve what you want without conflicting with Google's Terms and Conditions. The main thing is to put your mapView in a Frame layout, such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
 android:orientation="vertical" >          

 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/map_frame"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.7" >     

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:clickable="true"             
        android:apiKey="mySecretMapsApiKey"/>

 </FrameLayout>

 <ws.mentis.android.guardian.ui.MapNavBar
    android:id="@+id/map_nav"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" /> 

 </LinearLayout>
```

I had a number of buttons to included, so I created them in a custom widget (MapNavBar).
As you can see from the screen shot, the Google logo is still visible and in its normal place, within the new window.

[image: Screenshot of MapView]

This is working in Android 2.2
It also has the benefit that the standard zoom control also moves up so it doesn't interfere with your own buttons.

Comment: Yes you can do that but it's not the layout I asked for in the question :)

Comment: But it still gives you a way of achieving the end result you want.

Comment: Functionally, yes.Visually, no.

Comment: I appreciate you answering but this is not what I wanted/asked for :)

Comment: it is Nice idea, great

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation :

```
protected final void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)
```

onDraw is final method. **This can't be overridden at all.**

You can alternatively, show your buttons below mapview in layout aligned to parent bottom. This way you can have buttons at the position where you like and it will not obscure your google logo.

Comment: I actually never noticed the final keyword. It turned out to be impossible to do what I want to do :(

Comment: Annoying issue, with ABS the split actionbar with overlay feature will cover the logo thereby braking the terms. So overlay feature isn't an option here. Google themselves do something with their maps app in order to move the logo above the splitted overlay.

Answer (score 4):

Really old question, but maybe someone will make use of it. I made it to appear in right upper corner:

```
Rect rect = new Rect()
mMapView.getLocalVisibleRect(rect)
googleMap.setPadding(rect.width() - 100, 0, 0, rect.height() - 50)
```

If you want to place it somewhere else, you will need to have fun with setPadding

Also don't forget to hide UI buttons of google maps:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false)
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false)
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false)
```

There is one (at least) problem.
When using camera to center map on given point will not work properly. If camera movement is needed it will be better to just set padding to visible map fragment and it should work properly. Use rect to know what dimensions to put into    `setPadding`

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by doing the following.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="-30dp">

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map_frag_main"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will clip away the Google logo and no need for padding, just make sure you add a drawable or you will be violating TOS.

Comment: Err. you can also set the margin directly to the fragment. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

For **Compose**, just set the contentPadding

```
GoogleMap(
        properties = mapProperties,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        uiSettings = mapUiSettings,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 10.dp) <-----------------
    )
```

There you'll be able to push inner components (like the logo) by setting a padding to top, bottom, start, end, vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack, but you could try add a `MapView` it to a `FrameLayout,` setting the height of the `MapView` X dp larger than the `FrameLayout` so it gets clipped off, and adding a Logo `Drawable` wherever you wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything to do but using padding on GoogleMap object as stated by google maps documentation 
Note: As per the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices. Map padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to remove google watermark , Simply add this lines,**

```
View googleLogo = mapview.findViewWithTag("GoogleWatermark");

googleLogo.visibility = View.GONE
```

****and your issue will be solved.****