# Android: Google Maps API - Change position of maps toolbar

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the Google Maps API for Android. The following code enables the maps toolbar in the bottom right corner when I click on a Marker

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

However, I'd like this maps toolbar to appear in the TOP RIGHT corner of the map, rather than the default bottom right position.

How would I do this?

Comment: Use map padding as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20339849/2401535

Comment: Thank you - this worked! Until there is a clear way to change the position for the map toolbar alone, this will do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thought of commenting, But has low reputation. So:

As far as I know, there is no way to position it for now. It'll appear at its default position only.

As Nathan said I should add some alternative if possible. So,There is a work around: You can disable the map's toolbar. and can add appcompact's ToolBar anywhere in the layout.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: I would recommend, if possible, changing this to say something along the lines of "You can't, but here's something you can do."

Comment: Of course, But there must be _something_, he can do about it.

Comment: Right. If you can explain what that something might be, then this would be a perfectly legitimate answer. Otherwise, not so much.

Comment: What I meant by that is, there is nothing to do about changing position of existing toolbar UI of Google map. Hope that makes sense now. :)

Comment: It does, but unfortunately that does mean there's probably no answer anyone can give, if there simply is no workaround or partial solution or hack that can address the issue at all.

Comment: There can be a work around, But I answered what OP asked. That's all.

Comment: In digging up a reference to explain what I was recommending, I ran across [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer), which appears to have rather more useful guidance.

Answer (score 22):

This is an answer that i came across before as to how to move the toolbar to the bottom of the page. I hope this helps you.

```
//get reference to my location icon
    View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).
            getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));

    // and next place it, for example, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
    // position on right bottom
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

EDIT:
As per suggestions (of @Andro) this is the code to change the location of the map toolbar:

//get reference to my location icon

```
 View toolbar = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).
            getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("4"));

    // and next place it, for example, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    // position on right bottom
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

Comment: `View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).
            getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("4"));
` for maps toolbar

Comment: Thanks man, but you should edit your answer as @Andro suggest

Comment: why `parseInt("4")` ?

Comment: The mapView has different IDs for different views inside it. That is, different IDs for google text, map toolbar, location button etc. Toolbar has the ID 4. ID 2 is for location icon. :)

Comment: ohw,.right, thanks for the explanation. I'll change my answer right away,

Comment: This looks and feels extremely hacky. IMO you should never touch internal views this way because it may/will break on future releases of the library.

Comment: not working with  parseInt("4")  only work with parseInt("2")

Comment: Works great, thank you! Later versions of API started asking "not enough information" for findViewById. To resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267041/not-enough-information-to-infer-parameter-t-with-kotlin-and-android

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2021**

You should be able to move map UI controls (compass, my location, zoom, etc) by settings padding on your googleMap object. That's the only provided internal way as I found. Here's info from docs:

> Padding can be helpful when designing UIs that overlap some portion
> of the map. For example, in the below image, the map is padded along
> the top and right edges. Visible map controls and legal text will be
> displayed along the edges of the padded region

[image]

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding