# Changing Android Maps Toolbar animation

Tags: android, google-maps

I changed the position of my Maps Toolbar so that it is positioned in the left top corner of my Android App using this code:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams toolbarParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
 toolbarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
 toolbarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
 toolbarParams.setMargins(0, 15, 10, 0);
 toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarParams);
```

The position is correct, but once I click a marker, the toolbar flies in from the right side of the screen which looks bad. I'm trying to find a way to change the direction of that animation, so that it flies in from the left side of the screen, as its closer to the actual position.

I couldn't find any information on how to do it on the internet . Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I found a Stack Overflow ticket similar to you inquiry. You can disable the map's toolbar and add appcompat toolbar. 
Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy using *setSupportActionBar()* method.

Here's a link were I found the solution:
[Android: Google Maps API - Change position of maps toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688470/android-google-maps-api-change-position-of-maps-toolbar)

Here's a Official Google document for Toolbar:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: Thanks! Seems like what I've been looking for.