# Android: Customize map toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an App that uses Google map API and I'm trying to customize the Google map and GoTo buttons.

[image: one]

My idea is to put my own floatting buttons and make this buttons behave like  those two or the MyLocation button too. Is there a way to make this?

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar), it is stated that a toolbar appears at the bottom right of the map when a user taps a marker, by default. You can enable and disable the toolbar by calling `UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)`. As stated in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688470/android-google-maps-api-change-position-of-maps-toolbar), you can add [appcompact's ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) anywhere in the layout.

Comment: You can put your map into a relative layout, and also include your toolbar there. Then add a listener to your markers or to your map and when user taps on it make your toolbar visible