# Position of the Google logo in a Google map app (ios and android)

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I have a mobile application android and ios that uses the Google Map. However, I have views that hide the Google logo at the bottom left. I would like to move the logo up but I did not find how to do it! I searched in the Google documentation and also here on Stackoverflow but I did not find! Please, can you tell me if you can move the Google map logo on android (java) and ios (swift)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923472/relocate-google-logo-in-mapview

Comment: Archana thank you man ! googlemap.setpadding() works perfectly in android ! but in swift i don't know if theire is an equivalent ?

Comment: Great. try this `let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 300.0)
mapView.padding = mapInsets`

Comment: For swift  refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_padding

Comment: Archana + 10000000 lol thanks it works for swift !!

Answer (score 4):

You can move the **zoom controls, compass, copyright notices and Google logo** using `setPadding` for both Android  and iOS.

For Android : [GoogleMap.setPadding()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

For iOs : [GMSMapView.padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a66668a48bbc864faee1e8ba71e4c9bec)

Comment: Yes i know but i juste want to move the google logo (in swift) because Archana give me the answer for android : GoogleMap.setPadding()

Comment: you can try using GMSMapView.padding ..... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a66668a48bbc864faee1e8ba71e4c9bec

Comment: I think that you should remove you answer, or at least, update it with the proper content. The question is not about removing or altering the logo, but change its position. This thing is possible by using the `setPadding` as you already know since you posted the above comment.

Comment: @Iulian Popescu : updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your help and thanks to Archana who get the answer !!

For android :

```
googlemap.setpadding()
```

For swift :

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 300.0) mapView.padding = mapInsets
```